# How can I check if a website is secure using objective-c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ssl, uiwebview, wkwebview

So, I'm making a web browser.

And I would like to offer my user the ability to see whether a website is secure or not.

What parameters should I consider for a website to be secure?

How can I check if the website has an SSL certificate using objective-c?

Comment: What does "secure" mean?

Comment: I had the same question.

Comment: No site is secure. There is only a "secure enough" for a specific risk you are willing to take. And a large part of the sites security can not be checked from remote anyway, so the programming language does not matter.

Comment: Is the website's server is owner by you?